# Why does my open function need a single letter text string?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm going through lpthw and am messing with the open() function. The code I copied includes "target = open(filename, 'd'). I'm wondering why I have to include the 'd'?

I copied this code directly from the book. When I remove the 'd', the code fails, but I can't find any explanation of why it's necessary. I changed the 'd' to another letter and the code works fine.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print(f"We're going to erase {filename}.")
print("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")
print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")

input("?")

print("Opening the file...")
target = open(filename, 'd')

print("Truncating the file. Goodbye!")
target.truncate()
```

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument `('d')` is a  mode  which  tells the interpreter and developer which way the file will be used.

**Mode** : 
Including a mode argument is optional because a default value of ‘r’ will be assumed if it is omitted. The ‘r’ value stands for read mode, which is just one of many.

Comment: If you've already answered the question it might be worthy to explain what mode `'d'` does.